# How to track conversions for iphone apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

Is there any way to track which visitors end up installing our iphone apps?

Basically conversion tracking for apps?

(I know linkshare is a possibility - but they're US only. I need it to be worldwide because 50%+ of our installs are from outside the US)

I bet a bunch of other developers are wondering too. Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 2):

We just went through the same thing and we still haven't found a good solution. The most promising company we talked to was http://www.appsflyer.com/. We considered linkshare.com also but the solution is hacky to act as your own affiliate and they don't track free app conversions.

Comment: I finally tried appsflyer.com. It was pretty good. I'm just not quite sure if the stats are 100% correct. Specially since it's hard to track a conversion passing through itunes. I'll still stick with them. Because there's no better alternative. Very VERY helpful guys. I do recommend them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Flurry.com they have a great tracking product. You can keep track of events within the app (like what buttons were clicked, which ViewControllers were shown... etc).

Comment: i'm already using flurry. but flurry is an in-app analytics product. It doesn't give you a tracking link to track conversions OUTside of the app. any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[google mobile analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/overview.html)

[flurry analytics](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html)

both are useful products in usage tracking. flurry supports many platforms and google analytics has great interface.

Comment: once again - they both are in-app analytis. None of them provide the feature of tracking download conversions by traffic source.

Comment: if you need stats on downloads for your app, i think you can get it from itunes connect. is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.positionapp.com/
used to be pretty good last time I used it.
Recently they deliver much slower responses, check them out anyways.

Answer (score 0):

[Flurry](http://flurry.com) also has conversions to install tracking (outside the app).

[Appsflyer](http://www.appsflyer.com/) and [Mobileapptracking](http://www.mobileapptracking.com/) are also good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used distimo and I like their tracking system. You can also create campaigns with unique url and they will tell you, how many users did that particular campaign bring in.